# How to change styled-component styles by clicking on component with help of useState hook?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I want to change width of the StyledDivGrid component by clicking on it, but using this code, when I click on this div nothing happens. I can't realize what the problem is.
Help, pls

```
const StyledDivGrid = styled.div`
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: ${props=>props.width};
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightcoral;
`
function App() {
  let [state, setState] = useState(
    <StyledDivGrid width = {'120px'}></StyledDivGrid>
  )
  setState = () => {
      <StyledDivGrid width = {'240px'}></StyledDivGrid>;
  }
  
  return (
  
      <StyledDivGrid onClick = {() => setState()}>
        
      </StyledDivGrid>  
    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const StyledDivGrid = styled.div`
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   width: ${props=>props.width};
   height: 120px;
   position: relative;
   background-color: lightcoral;
`
function App() {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState("120px")
   
  return (

  <StyledDivGrid onClick={ () => setWidth("240px")} width={width}>
    
  </StyledDivGrid>  

  );
}
```

Didn't check the code and I guess you are using styled-components , i hope this is useful